# Laravel Telescope not working on a fresh install (wrong path)

Tags: php, laravel

I am using XAMPP and I installed a fresh Laravel 5.8 with composer **create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel larascopy** in *C:\xampp\htdocs\larascopy*

I can access it by going to:
http://localhost/larascopy/public/

And then installed Telescope with these commands from the Guide:

```
composer require laravel/telescope
php artisan telescope:install
php artisan migrate
```

Then I can open Telescope like this
http://localhost/larascopy/public/telescope

But all the links are wrong! They are pointing to:
http://localhost/telescope/...

So I get all these errors in Console..

```
POST http://localhost/telescope/telescope-api/commands?tag=&before=&take=50&family_hash= 404 (Not Found)
POST http://localhost/telescope/telescope-api/commands?tag=&before=&take=50&family_hash= 404 (Not Found)
POST http://localhost/telescope/telescope-api/schedule?tag=&before=&take=50&family_hash= 404 (Not Found)
app.js?id=8776cf12ba6d7c72f145:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Is there a way to tell telescope the correct path?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found a solution (for anyone else who might come across this issue).

1. Open: \vendor\laravel\telescope\resources\views\layout.blade.php
2. Change these lines

```
<!-- Global Telescope Object -->
<script>
   window.Telescope = @json($telescopeScriptVariables);
</script>
```

to this

```
<!-- Global Telescope Object -->
<script>
   window.Telescope = @json($telescopeScriptVariables);
   window.Telescope.path = 'your_project_folder/public/telescope';
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed it for me after hours of trying to solve this lol...

Comment: You should never edit vendor files. They will be overridden during composer update.

Comment: Never edit vendor files.. but if it's only for local i think this should do.

Answer (score 15):

You need to change Telescope path by **overriding** telescope layout, for that you need to follow some steps as given below.

> This solution is also work for telescope laravel project created in
>   sub-folders.

**Step 1: Copy layout file from following path** 
File Path: *project_directory*/vendor/laravel/telescope/resources/views/layout.blade.php

**Step 2: Paste that copied file to following path** 
File Path: *project_directory*/resources/views/vendor/telescope/layout.blade.php

> You need to create vendor/telescope folder in resources/views
>   directory.

**Step 3: Change layout.blade.php file** 
        File Path: *project_directory*/resources/views/vendor/telescope/layout.blade.php

Original:

```
<!-- Global Telescope Object -->
<script>
    window.Telescope = @json($telescopeScriptVariables);
</script>
```

Updated:

```
<!-- Global Telescope Object -->
<script>
    window.Telescope = @json($telescopeScriptVariables);

    var telescopePath = "{{ ltrim(parse_url(url(config('telescope.path')))['path'], '/') }}";
    window.Telescope.path = telescopePath;
</script>
```

Comment: it's the best solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Well, overriding the config superglobal directly inside of view is not the right way to do:

You can do the same thing more properly by writing this into your .env file presents on your project's root folder:

```
TELESCOPE_PATH=yourSubFolder/telescope
```

Then in your view config('telescope.path') will return yourSubFolder/telescope

Modify the vendor's views may causes problems when your project goes to production: vendors will be reloaded by composer to the latest version and your modifications will be erased.

The .env file will not.

**But anyway, this doesn't debug my telescope at all for me:**

I was able to load Telescope on localhost/myproject/public/myproject/public/telescope . All the links was good: localhost/myproject/public/telescope/queries, localhost/myproject/public/telescope/requests, etc...
But telescope still wasn't loading datas.

**To fully debug**, I tried to config Apache and make a VirtualHost for my project.
Then Telescope was fully working on http://myproject.local/telescope

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to not simply set the proper path for your web server? You may want to change your Nginx or Apache root to be `larascopy/public/` then your URL should be `localhost/telescope`. It's possible that it doesn't like being installed as a sub directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this 3 commands Reference:  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cannot-access-into-laravel-telescope-dashboard

```
composer update && php artisan optimize && php artisan optimize:clear
```